# Comeau vs g++ [Yet another bug]

Tags: c++, private, comeau

Consider the following **test**<sup>1</sup> code

```
struct A {
 private:         
     class face;
     friend class face; 
};

struct A::face {};    

template <typename _CharT>
struct C : public A::face
{};

int main()
{
  C<int> x;
}
```

Is this code well formed? I tested it under g++ and comeau. g++ compiles it fine whereas comeau gives the following error message (which I think is correct)

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 12: error: class "A::face" (declared at line 9) is inaccessible
      struct C : public A::face
                           ^
          detected during instantiation of class "C<_CharT> [with _CharT=int]"
                    at line 17
```

Which compiler is correct in this case? Comeau is one of the most standard conforming compiler that I know of. Is g++ wrong again?

(1) This is not a real life code.

Comment: clang++ 3.0 compiles it too, except it points out that it's `class face` in one place and `struct face` in another.

Comment: @Cubbi : Yes tried on clang too. Compiles it erroneously.

Comment: Intel 11.1 has a telling diagnostic `test.cc(10): warning #525: class "A::face" (declared at line 7) is an inaccessible type (allowed for cfront compatibility)` Sun and Microsoft also refuse to compile.

Comment: Both Comeau and Intel use the same EDG front end right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's incorrect. `face` is private, so it's not accessible from C. This would only be legal if C had been friended from A, not `face`. `face` is a private member, and so `friend`ing it has no effect.